# keras: how to block convolution layer weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

[Here](http://gist.github.com/joelouismarino/a2ede9ab3928f999575423b9887abd14) I have a GoogleNet model for Keras. Is there any possibile way to block the changing of the individual layers of network? I want to block the first two layers of pretrained model from changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By 'block the changing of the individual layers' I am assuming you don't want to train those layers, that is you don't want to modify the loaded weights(possibly learnt in previous training).

if so you can pass `trainable=False` to the layer and the parameters wont be used for the training update rule.

Example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_dim=100),
    Dense(output_dim=10),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
])

model.summary()

model2 = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_dim=100,trainable=False),
    Dense(output_dim=10),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
])

model2.summary()
```

You can see in the model summary for the 2nd model the parameters are counted as Non-trainable ones.

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 32)            3232        dense_input_1[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            330         dense_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_2[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 3,562
Trainable params: 3,562
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
dense_3 (Dense)                  (None, 32)            3232        dense_input_2[0][0]              
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                  (None, 10)            330         dense_3[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)        (None, 10)            0           dense_4[0][0]                    
====================================================================================================
Total params: 3,562
Trainable params: 330
Non-trainable params: 3,232
```

Comment: No problem.. if it answers your question, can you mark it so.

Comment: I'm trying, but unfortunately, I haven't enought reputation for marking your answer((((

Comment: You should be able to accept answers, though not upvote as upvoting requires +15 reputation. Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work